# How to retrieve data using a strong typed model in LinqToSql

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

This code works fine.

```
using (ContextDB db = new ContextDB())
{
            var custAcct  = (from c in db.CustAccts
                           select new 
                            {
                                c.AcctNo,
                                c.Company,
                                c.UserName
                            }).ToList();
```

But this one doesn't

```
public class CustAcct
{
        public int AcctNo { get; set; }      
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
}

 ....
 ....
 ....

   using (ContextDB db = new ContextDB())
        {
            CustAcct custAcct  = (from c in db.CustAccts
                           select new 
                            {
                                c.AcctNo,
                                c.Company,
                                c.UserName
                            }).ToList();
```

It returns this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'EMailReader.Models.CustAcct'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I used Google, found many related topics but still couldn't put it to work using the available solutions

I just need to return data to a strong typed model.

EDITED:

After more research I found this solution bellow, but I wonder why I cannot retrieve directly in the list from LinqToSql.

```
       List<CustAcct> temp = new List<CustAcct>();
        IEnumerable<dynamic> items = custAcct;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            temp.Add(new CustAcct()
            {
                AcctNo = item.AcctNo,
                Company = item.Company,
                UserName = item.UserName,
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re defining those properties by creating new Class. And this will override LINQ2SQL generated class.

Just change "public class CustAcct" to "public partial class CustAcct".

This will solve your problem, and you do not need to define those properties again. Remove those from your class. Those will be automatically create for you.

If you can just post your class, and I will change it for you.

//Shyam